# Помогите.Неправильная сортировка!

Tags: c, массивы, сортировка, пузырьковая-сортировка

Помогите.Неправильная сортировка!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>




void print(int m,int n,int a[n][m])
{
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
        for (j=0;j<m;++j)
        {
            printf("%d  ",a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void sort(int m,int n,int a[m][n])
{
    int i,j,t;
    for (i=0;i<n;++i)
        for (j=0;j<m;++j)
            if(a[i][j]>a[i][j+1])
        {
            t=a[i][j];
            a[i][j]=a[i][j+1];
            a[i][j+1]=t;
        }
}

int main()
{
    int n,m,i,j; //n - строка m - столбец
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUSSIAN");
    printf("Введите размер матрицы: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    scanf("%d", &m);
    int a [n][m];
    for (i=0;i<n;++i)
        for (j=0;j<m;++j)
        a[i][j]=rand()%10;
    print(m,n,a);
    sort(m,n,a);
    print(m,n,a);
    return 0;

}
```

Не могу понять почему сортирует не так как нужно,да еще и значения левые присваивает
[image: ошибка]

Comment: Это вообще-то не сортировка, а только один проход пузырьковой сортировки в каждой строке. Кроме того, попутан размер по вертикали и горизонтали. Откуда вообще идея с двумерным массивом взялась? Для них нет общепринятого определения сортированности.

Comment: Задание такое.Юзал такой способ много раз,но на плюсах.Хз что сейчас не так.Мне нужно строки отсортировать

Comment: @JohnnyTravolta , так какая у вас, в итоге задача : отсортировать всю матрицу или каждую её строчку?

Comment: @gromoff97 Каждую строку

Answer (score 1):

Если задача была по возрастанию отсортировать каждую строчку матрицы, то есть превратить, например,

```
{ {65,78,12},
  {32,4,17},
  {48,29,81} }
```

В это

```
{ {12,65,78},
  {4,17,32},
  {29,48,81} }
```

То для для каждой строчки вы можете использовать.
[правильную](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%A1%D0%B8_%D0%B2_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) "пузырьковую" сортировку.
Основная ошибка кроется в ваших "for" : сравните вашу реализацию с реализацией по ссылке :)

### Может, всё-таки ваша задача отсортировать другое? :)

Если вам нужно отсорировать матрицу, то есть получить что-то в виде

```
{ {4,12,17},
  {29,32,48},
  {65,78,81} }
```

То можете записать исходный двумерный массив в созданный одномерный массив размером `m * n`, выполнить для него сортировку пузырьком и вернуть значения обратно в этот двумерный массив.

Поскольку тэг 'C', то сделал предположительно правильную реализацию на 'C' (извините, если для вас комментарии носят избыточный характер : всё ради вас):

```
int sort_matrix(size_t m, size_t n, int** matrix)
{
    /*валидация аргументов*/
    if ( 0 == m || 0 == n || NULL == matrix ) return -1;

    //Выделяем память для одномерного массива
    int* buffer = ( int* ) malloc ( sizeof(int) * m * n );

    /*если память не выделилась*/
    if ( NULL == buffer ) return -2;

    /*записываем значения двумерного массива в один*/
    size_t i,j,buffer_counter = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i < m; i++ )
        for ( j = 0; j < n; j++ )
        {
            buffer[buffer_counter] = matrix[i][j];
            buffer_counter++;
        }

    /*сортируем пузырьком, и если сортировка не удалась*/
    if ( 0 != bubble_sort(m * n, buffer) ) return -3;

    /*записываем значения отсортированного одномерного массива обратно в наш двумерный*/
    buffer_counter = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i < m; i++ )
        for ( j = 0; j < n; j++ )
        {
            matrix[i][j] = buffer[buffer_counter];
            buffer_counter++;
        }

    /*освобождаем выделенную для buffer память*/
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Сортировка пузырьком у меня следующая:

```
int bubble_sort(size_t buffer_size, int* buffer)
{
    if ( 0 == buffer_size || 1 == buffer_size || NULL == buffer ) return -1;

    int tmp;
    size_t i, j;

    for( i = 0 ; i < buffer_size - 1; i++ )
        for( j = 0 ; j < buffer_size - i - 1 ; j++ ) 
            if( buffer[j] > buffer[j+1] )
            {
                tmp = buffer[j];
                buffer[j] = buffer[j+1];
                buffer[j+1] = tmp;
            }

    return 0;
}
```

Ну и `main` вам для теста :

```
int main()
{
    /*  m - количество строк,
        n - количество столбцов */
    size_t m,n;

    puts("Введите размер матрицы:");
    scanf("%lu", &m);
    scanf("%lu", &n);

    /*выделим память для двухмерного массива*/
    int** a = ( int** ) malloc( sizeof( int* ) * m );
    for (size_t j = 0; j < m; j++)
        a[j] = ( int* ) malloc( sizeof( int* ) * n);

    /*воспользуемся генератором псевдослучайных чисел для инициализации матрицы*/
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < n; j++)
            a[i][j] = rand() % 10;

    puts("before :");
    print(m,n,a);

    sort_matrix(m,n,a);

    puts("after :");
    print(m,n,a);

    /*освободим выделенную память*/
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

А в `print` ничего не поменялось за исключением сигнатуры:

```
void print(int m, int n, int** a){...}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @JohnnyTravolta Не за что :) Если вы считаете, что кто-то ответил на ваш вопрос, то лучше просто отметить его правильным :)